# Javascript/Jquery Load Callback and Writing a Base Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

This might be a possible duplicate question but I do not know how to phrase the search for it. I'm not that familiar with JS properties.

**CASE:**

Lets say I create some element types such as Text,Image,Audio,Video etc. and suppose I give them the same abilities such as drag, rotate, resize etc. For simplicity, lets consider this two elements: Text and Image.

**PROBLEM:**

Lets say I need to get the sizes of those two elements and set those to their wrapper div.

- Text element is simple, i can just get the size immediately and set the size of wrapper div.
- Image element waits for the load of the image and its size can be set only after the load happens i.e. in its load callback.

**SIMPLE EXAMPLE**

```
function createText(){
    var aDiv = createWrapperDiv(); // <div class="element"></div>
    var anElem = $('<textarea></textarea>')
    aDiv.append(anElem)

    // can set immediately
    aDiv.attr('width', anElem.width());
    aDiv.attr('height', anElem.height());

    // Some other size-DEPENDENT and size-INDEPENDENT stuff can both be done here.
    sizeDependentStuff();
    sizeIndependentStuff();

}

function createImage(){
    var aDiv = createWrapperDiv(); // <div class="element"></div>
    var anElem = $('<img>')
    aDiv.append(anElem)

    // need to wait for element to load.
    anElem.attr('src',imageUrl)
    anElem.load(function(e) {
        aDiv.attr('width', e.currentTarget.width());
        aDiv.attr('height', e.currentTarget.height());

        // Some other size-DEPENDENT stuff.
        sizeDependentStuff();
    });

    // Some other size-INDEPENDENT stuff.
    sizeIndependentStuff();

}
```

**WHAT I WANT:**

I want to define a createSimpleElement function ( something similar to a Factory) that takes type and does both sizeDependentStuff and sizeIndependentStuff so I can reuse the same code. Note that i have more than 2 types and number can increase. I can not find a suitable way to tackle the load process.

I hope it is clear and please consider that I am still in the learning process.

Thanks.

Comment: you would use the search functionality top right of Stack Overflow. Or alternatively you can use google, and the parameter "site:stackoverflow.com" to search for it

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not know how to "phrase" the search about this issue. Sorry for the unclearness.

Comment: Oh I see. Well the way you explained it I can summarize that you're looking to create elements dynamically without having to use the code over and over again? Create a function with the common code and have it output an object, then pass a name as a parameter to make it unique, and in a loop where you create the dynamic elements, call that function...

Comment: What is your question? I got lost in the explanation. You were saying something about images, and waiting for them to load, but then in your sum up and what i want sectiosn you completely ignored that.

Comment: I tried to be clear but messed up I guess. I simplified things, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
function base(parentElement, element){
    parentElement.append(element);
    parentElement.attr('width', element.width());
    parentElement.attr('width', element.width());
    /*other common properties...*/
}

function createText(){
    var aDiv = createWrapperDiv();
    var anElem = $('<textarea></textarea>')
    base(aDiv, anElem);    
}

function createImage(){
    var aDiv = createWrapperDiv();
    var anElem = $('<img>')
    anElem.attr('src',imageUrl)
    anElem.load(function(e) {
        base(aDiv, anElem);   
    });

    // Some other size-INDEPENDENT stuff.

  }
}
```

Comment: always set the src after binding the load event. Always include an explanation of what changed and why in the answer.